# ARIMA model returning a KeyError

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, arima

After fitting the train dataset, I'm trying to predict with the fitted ARIMA model but I'm getting this error message  ==> The `start` argument could not be matched to a location related to the index of the data.'

pred = model_fit.predict(start=test_oilPrice.index.min(), end=test_oilPrice.index.max())[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXX2a.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwvM6.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsdK9.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.